# Parameters not populating with Ajax Call

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

This is my controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public bool Sync(int? id, string name)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Here is my ajax request call that I am trying to make to this controller:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var buttonClicked = document.getElementById("syncLegacy");
    buttonClicked.addEventListener('click', function () { syncLegacyMake(); }, false);

    function syncLegacyMake() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Legacy/Sync',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify({
                id: $("#Id").val(),
                name: $("#Name").val()
            }),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data) {

            },
            error: function () {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
    }
```

The controller gets hit however there are no values to the parameters. The values are both null.

When I look at the call itself on chrome console, the values are populated as these under Request Payload in the headers:

{id: "01", name: "Titan"}
id
:
"01"
name
:
"Titan"

Could anyone point out what I am doing wrong here? I have been able to do the same in .net 4.6.1 framework so not sure if framework changed has caused this?

Comment: Remove contentType: and JSON.stringify( and check once

Comment: You don't need to use `json.stringify` for data. Simply use `data:{id: $("#Id").val(),name: $("#Name").val() },`.

Comment: And you are returning `bool` from your action method, so you don't need to specify `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'` as well.

Comment: public bool Sync(int? id, string name) remove ? from argument

Comment: @mmushtaq No. "contentType" specifies the content type of the data being **sent** to the server. So it should be ok in this instance, because OP is sending a JSON object (or would be, if they hadn't stringified it). Removing it probably would be ok as well, but not for the reason you gave. "dataType" specified the type of data expected in the response. In this case, since it's not specified, jQuery will guess intelligently. Read the documentation on the various parameters here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: @ADyson thanks for pointing out. My mistake..

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the following things:

### Using a Dto instead of separate simple types:

```
public class SyncDto
{
    public int? Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
// Controller action:
[HttpPost]
public bool Sync(SyncDto input)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

### Make Jquery stringify itself

Let jquery figure your ajax call out itself:

```
     $.ajax({
        url: '/Legacy/Sync',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            id: $("#Id").val(),
            name: $("#Name").val()
        }
    });
```

Comment: Normally i would use a dto but wanted a simple function hence I have gone with mmushtaq and ADyson recommendation